# GameCenter says "Missed Method" and doesn't report scores

Tags: objective-c, xcode, game-center

I've been looking for answer in a few similar threads, but I couldn't find the properly one for my issue.

I have this in viewDidLoad

```
self.currentLeaderBoard = [leaderboards objectForKey:[defaults objectForKey:@"Level"]];

if ([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]) {

    self.gameCenterManager= [[GameCenterManager alloc] init];
    [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate: self];
    [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Current device doesn't support GameCenter");

}
```

I try to send the score in this way:

```
NSLog(@"Category %@", self.currentLeaderBoard);

[self.gameCenterManager reportScore: 20 forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
[self.gameCenterManager reloadHighScoresForCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
```

I have also added this to fix, but it didn't help:

```
- (void) processGameCenterAuth: (NSError*) error
{
    if(error == NULL)
    {
        [self.gameCenterManager reloadHighScoresForCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
        NSLog(@"GAMECENTER OK");
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Game Center Account Required" 
                                                        message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Try Again..." otherButtonTitles: NULL];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

But the effect is always the same:

```
2012-04-15 11:34:31.987 Colors[40146:1bb03] authenticateWithCompletionHandler: enter
2012-04-15 11:34:32.009 Colors[40146:1bb03] authenticateWithCompletionHandler: exit
2012-04-15 11:34:32.010 Colors[40146:1bb03] NORMAL MODE
2012-04-15 11:34:33.163 Colors[40146:1bb03] GAMECENTER OK
2012-04-15 11:34:33.368 Colors[40146:1bb03] Missed Method
2012-04-15 11:34:33.773 Colors[40146:1bb03] Category 2
2012-04-15 11:34:33.851 Colors[40146:1bb03] Missed Method
2012-04-15 11:34:33.989 Colors[40146:1bb03] Missed Method
```

As you can see it says "Missed Method" at the beginning of app working and also when I try to report scores. It doesn't report scores at all (I have tried with 2 different accounts on simulator) - nothing is displayed in GC.
Surely I checked if the categories are properly set in iTunes Connect and they seem to be.
http://cl.ly/183a2A2p1M0A2k2c3U2B

Please tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it... Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this yet by any chance? I'm stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I already goes through the same problem. Missed method is not a big issue you can overlook it.

The problem can be from :

- The version of your simulator, if you have the 5.1 maybe you should try 4.3 it can make your score magically apear x).
- If you have only one user in your leaderboard it basically won't be shown, try making several acount report scores.

good luck